# Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [bucket_sort] - elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't seem to put results of elastic query in order.

I store memory utilization statistics in elasticsearch. Example of a document looks like this:

```
{
   "Component": "ABC",
   "memUsage" : "100",
   "Timestamp" : "1562072516001"
}
```

I'm trying to count average memory utilization per component in a given time frame. The query without sorting works fine.

Results of a query without sorting:

```
"aggregations": {"averages": {"buckets":    {
  "ABC":       {
     "doc_count": 1,
     "memUsageAVG": {"value": 254}
  },
  "XYZ":       {
     "doc_count": 1,
     "memUsageAVG": {"value": 203}
  }
 }}}
```

However I'm struggling to put those results in ascending order (order by memory utilization or order by name).

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
  "bool":{  
     "must":[  
        {  
           "range":{  
              "Timestamp":{  
                 "gte":"1562072516001",
                 "lte":"1562072516001"
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
   },
   "aggs":{  
  "averages":{  
     "filters":{  
        "filters":{  
           "ABC":{  
              "match":{  
                 "Component":"ABC"
              }
           },
           "XYZ":{  
              "match":{  
                 "Component":"XYZ"
              }
           }
        }
     },
     "aggs":{  
        "memUsageAVG":{  
           "avg":{  
              "field":"memUsage"
           }
        },
        "final_sort":{  
           "bucket_sort":{  
              "sort":[  
                 {  
                    "memUsageAVG":{  
                       "order":"desc"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

}
}

Executing this query results with an error:
"type": "unknown_named_object_exception",
"reason": "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [bucket_sort]",
"line": 30,
"col": 23

Comment: What Elasticsearch version are you using?  The query you provided works fine for me on ES 7.1.1, and note that the `bucket_sort` aggregation wasn't added until ES 6.1.0: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/release-notes-6.1.0.html#_new_features_2

Comment: That might be the problem. I'm using 5.6.16. Is there a way I can put my results in order using any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in your comment, the reason this is not working is because the `bucket_sort` parent aggregation was added in Elasticsearch 6.1.0 ([release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/release-notes-6.1.0.html#_new_features_2)) and you're running ES 5.6.16.

You should be able to accomplish the same feat in ES 5.x (and 6.x/7.x for that matter) using a `terms` aggregation instead and ordering the buckets by sub-aggregation:

```js
POST /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "averages": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Component",
        "size": 10,                // Recommend keeping this low-ish to limit memory usage 
        "include": ["ABC", "XYZ"], // Optionally limit to specific Components
        "order": {
          "memUsageAVG": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "memUsageAVG": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "memUsage"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note 1:** This requires that the `Component` field is `keyword` analyzed in your mapping.  If you didn't explicitly define a mapping for this index, that field would have defaulted to `text` analyzed instead and you will see errors along the lines of: `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default`.  For more information, see docs on the [Keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/keyword.html) and [creating an index with mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-create-index.html#mappings)

**Note 2:** that the `include` clause on the agg isn't necessary, but if you know which components you want to aggregate over then it can only help performance.

Comment: Thank you, rusnyder! I use templates to keep proper mappings. Your code did the work.

Comment: @rusnyder -- Can you explain how we sort other than the numeric field? I wanted grouping and that grouped result to be sorted with id or name field. I am using ElasticSearch 5.3

Comment: @Sharvil Using the original question's sample data for reference:  You mean you want the resulting buckets to be ordered by the "Component" name or id? So descending order by name would order the buckets "XYZ", "ABC"?

Comment: @rusnyder - Yes. I wanted to get buckets sorted on the Text/Keyword field. I can do that for Numeric fields..

Comment: You can sort by the term being bucketed (i.e. - in this case, the `Component` field) by  using `"order": {"_term": "asc"}` instead of ordering by the `memUsageAVG` subaggregation.

For more information, see the terms aggregation docs (the second example from those docs demonstrates this): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order

Comment: @rusnyder -- I am getting an error it expects numeric field and my term field is a string. Can you please look into this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539380/elasticsearch-aggregation-sorting-in-on-nonnumric-field-5-3 

I have added query and basic dummy data also..

Comment: The above query as you said using ```{"_term": "asc"}``` will give result in ascending order but based on the "id" fields. I wanted that based on name field.

Comment: To answer this question specifically (not the other post linked): The above query will give a result in ascending order on the field that the `terms` aggregation is aggregating over.  I'd encourage that if you want to sort by the `name` field instead, you should switch the `terms` aggregation to aggregate over the `name` field.  Sorting by a text field different than was grouped on is not supported nor does it make sense because there might be duplicates of the `name` field in each `id` bucket and there's no way to resolve those.

Comment: Thank you Rusnyder. I cleared my doubts. Thanks for the help.