# ElasticSearch Aggregation + Sorting in on NonNumric Field 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I wanted to aggregate the data on a different field and also wanted to get the aggregated data on sorted fashion based on the name.

My data is :

```
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp001_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 10.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 01"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0001"
        ],
        "ranking": [
             "2.0"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp002_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 85146.375,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 02"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0001"
        ],
        "ranking": [
             "10.0"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp003_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 20.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 03"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0002"
        ],        
        "ranking": [
             "-1.0"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "testing-aggregation",
    "_type": "employee",
    "_id": "emp004_local000000000000001",
    "_score": 5.0,
    "_source": {
        "name": [
            "Person 04"
        ],
        "groupbyid": [
            "group0002"
        ],
        "ranking": [
             "2.0"
        ]
    }
}
```

My query :

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "name:emp*^1000.0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "groupbyid": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "groupbyid.raw",
                "order": {
                    "top_hit_agg": "desc"
                },
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_hit_agg": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My mapping is :

```
{
    "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
            "lower_case_sort": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
            }
        }
    },
    "groupbyid": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "index": "analyzed",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting data based on the average of the relevance of grouped records. Now, what I wanted is the first club the records based on the groupid and then in each bucket sort the data based on the name field.

I wanted grouping on one field and after that grouped bucket, I want to sort on another field. This is sample data.

There are other fields like created_on, updated_on. I also wanted to get sorted data based on that field. also get the data by alphabetically grouped.

I wanted to sort on the non-numeric data type(string). I can do the numeric data type.

I can do it for the ranking field but not able to do it for the name field. It was giving the below error.

```
Expected numeric type on field [name], but got [text];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a few things, so I'll try to answer them in turn.

### Step 1: Sorting buckets by relevance

> I am getting data based on the average of the relevance of grouped records.

If this is what you're attempting to do, it's not what the aggregation you wrote is doing.  Terms aggregations default to sorting the buckets by the number of documents in each bucket, descending.  To sort the groups by "average relevance" (which I'll interpret as "average `_score` of documents in the group"), you'd need to add a sub-aggregation on the score and sort the terms aggregation by that:

```
"aggregations": {
  "most_relevant_groups": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "groupbyid.raw",
      "order": {
        "average_score": "desc"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "average_score": {
        "avg": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "_score",
            "lang": "painless",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 2: Sorting employees by name

> Now, what I wanted is the first club the records based on the groupid and then in each bucket sort the data based on the name field.

To sort the documents within each bucket, you can use a `top_hits` aggregation:

```
"aggregations": {
  "most_relevant_groups": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "groupbyid.raw",
      "order": {
        "average_score": "desc"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "employees": {
        "top_hits": {
          "size": 10,  // Default will be 10 - change to whatever
          "sort": [
            {
              "name.lower_case_sort": {
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 3: Putting it all together

Putting the both the above together, the following aggregation should suit your needs (note that I used a function_score query to simulate "relevance" based on ranking - your query can be whatever and just needs to be any query that produces whatever relevance you need):

```
POST /testing-aggregation/employee/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "ranking"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupbyid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "groupbyid.raw",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "average_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_score": {
          "avg": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "_score",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        },
        "employees": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10,
            "sort": [
              {
                "name.lower_case_sort": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the step2 -- How can we do sorting first and then based on the sorting aggregate the data? I wanted data like this 

`Name: B1
GroupByID: group01
|
Name: C1
GroupByID: group01 | 
Name: A1
GroupByID: group02 |
Name: N1
GroupByID: group03 |
Name: AB1
GroupByID: group04`

I wanted data in this fashion. 
`group02
-A1|
group04
-AB1|
group01
-B1
-C1|
group03
-N1`

Comment: Also many thank for clearing some doubts related to the aggregation and sorting.

Comment: It sounds like you’re still trying to globally order the results by a text field that isn’t being aggregated over, which again, isn’t supported.  With terms aggregations you can (1) create buckets of documents al sharing the same value for a particular field, (2) order those buckets based on something numeric, and (3) order documents _within_ each bucket.  I don’t know the exact problem you’re trying to solve, but if you really need to order the groups by the names of people in them, consider some post-processing if the ES results

Comment: Let's consider the scenario. One customer has many orders. I want to get all the customer name and their order details on ascending order by customer name. So for the same, I need to add sort on customer name and grouping needs to be done on the orderId. Consider under a single index, there are two types - customer and order. Each order record has a field called customerId.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to group by order Id.  From your problem statement: "I want to get all the customer name and their order details on ascending order by customer name.".  This sounds like (expressed in SQL): `SELECT FROM orders GROUP BY orders.customer_id ORDER BY orders.customer_name`.  In this case, your index shouldn't have _two_ types of documents, only one: `order`.  Denormalize enough customer information onto each order to support the grouping/sorting you need (i.e. - customer_id).

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you for clearing my doubts and answering my silly questions. Much appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure thing @Sharvil!  Hopefully this helped